# installing 'EdpModuleLayouts' to zendframework 2

Tags: layout, zend-framework2

i am trying to install 'EdpModuleLayouts'

i have followed the instruction  for the module [here:](https://github.com/EvanDotPro/EdpModuleLayouts/blob/master/README.md)

i also followed the issue [here:](https://github.com/EvanDotPro/EdpModuleLayouts/issues/4)

i. e; I placed the following code in my application.config.php?

```
return array(
    'modules' => array(
        ... ,
        'EdpModuleLayouts'
   )
);
```

i then placed the following code in my module config

```
'view_manager' => array(
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            'workers' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
            'Workers/layout' => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml'
        ),
    ),
    'module_layouts' => array(
    'Workers' => 'Workers/layout'
),
```

i got the following error report:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\View\Exception\RuntimeException'
>   with message 'Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer::render: Unable to render
>   template "Workers/layout"; resolver could not resolve to a file' in
>   zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer.php
>   on line 499

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is so specific.

```
Unable to render template "Workers/layout"
```

This means that there is no template **Workers/layout** defined within the `view_manager` configuration. And the trick here is that you made a simple mistake of placing the configuration at the wrong place.

**template_path_stack** is used to give the `view_manager` information about some **folders** where template files are mapped going by their file-path.

**template_map** is used to give the `view_manager` information about which file covers a specific template.

The difference of the two can easily be seen when checking the [`module.config.php of the ZendSkeletonApplication`](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/blob/master/module/Application/config/module.config.php#L85-L93). With this in mind, all you have to do is to change your configuration.

Another hint: don't CamelCase configuration keys, keep them lowercased ;)

```
'view_manager' => array(
    'template_path_stack' => array(
        'workers' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
    ),
    'template_map' => array(
        // consider to make this lowercase "workers/layout"
        'Workers/layout' => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml'
    )
),
'module_layouts' => array(
    'Workers' => 'Workers/layout'
),
```

Comment: thank you sam. brilliant advice. it worked perfectly